# bootstrap table hover class not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

wondering is this the cause of why my bootstrap hover class is not working. Due to the way i use jquery to populate my data when page load?

here is my table html

```
 <table id="currency" class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">JPY</th>
        <th scope="col">USD</th>
        <th scope="col">SGD</th>
        <th scope="col">AUD</th>
        <th scope="col">THB</th>
        <th scope="col">CNY</th>
        <th scope="col">TWD</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and i am using something like this with express to populate my data during the page load

```
jQuery.get('/currency', function(dreams) {
console.log(dreams)
dreams.forEach(function(dream) {
  $('<tr>').appendTo("#currency>tbody");
  $('<td></td>').text(dream.date_time).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.jpy).toFixed(5)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.usd).toFixed(2)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.sgd).toFixed(2)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.aud).toFixed(2)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.thb).toFixed(3)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.cny).toFixed(3)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.twd).toFixed(3)).appendTo('#currency>tbody');
  $('</tr>').appendTo("#currency>tbody");
})
})
```

is this the cause of it not working?

Comment: Any error in console. Because your code worked for me with hardcoded values:-https://jsfiddle.net/L6195cr8/

Comment: nope, no error in console tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe will help you

You need append `td` to `tr` and `tr` to `tbody`.Your code is append all to `#currency>tbody`

```
jQuery.get('/currency', function(dreams) {
    console.log(dreams)
    dreams.forEach(function(dream) {
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      $('<td></td>').text(dream.date_time).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.jpy).toFixed(5)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.usd).toFixed(2)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.sgd).toFixed(2)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.aud).toFixed(2)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.thb).toFixed(3)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.cny).toFixed(3)).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(parseFloat(dream.twd).toFixed(3)).appendTo(tr);
      tr.appendTo($('#currency>tbody'));
    })
 })
```

Comment: thanks alot, is working for me now, which part i am doing it wrong?

Comment: You need append `td` to `tr` and `tr` to `tbody`.Your code is append all to  `#currency>tbody`

Comment: @user1897151 you are appending `<td>` directly to `<tbody>` not `<tr>`